# How to determine if the camera button is half pressed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating a small test camera application, and I would like to be able to implement a feature that allows focus text bars to be present on the screen while the hardware camera button is pressed half way down. I created a camera_ButtonHalfPress event to perform the focus action, but I am unsure of how to toggle the text bars I would like to show on the screen accordingly. Essentially, my goal would be to show the text bars while the camera button is pressed half way down, and then remove them if the button is pressed all the way or the button is released before being pressed all the way down. The button being released is the part I am having trouble with. What I have is as follows:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

         ...

         //Event is fired when the button is half pressed
         CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += camera_ButtonHalfPress;

         //Event is fired when the button is fully pressed
         CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += camera_ButtonFullPress;                   

     }

    private void camera_ButtonHalfPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //camera.Focus();

        // Show the focus brackets.
        focusBrackets.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void camera_ButtonFullPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hide the focus brackets.
        focusBrackets.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        camera.CaptureImage();
        }
    }
```

Currently, if the the user decides to release the camera button before it is pressed all the way, the focus brackets persist on the screen. How might I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe to the `CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed` event of the camera, and hide the text bars inside.

Comment: I could not find any release event, would you show me how this is impelemented?

Comment: Well how did you register the ButtonFullPress and ButtonHalfPress events? I was thinking about something like: `CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += this.CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;`

Comment: I just found the solution, the CameraButtons class contains ShutterKeyReleased. Thanks for your insight, I added my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

If you add CameraButtons.ShutterKeyReleased to the OnNavigatedTo event, then the problem is solved!

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)  
{  
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);  

     ...  

     CameraButtons.ShutterKeyReleased -= camera_ButtonReleased;  //add corresponding event handler elsewhere

     ...                

 }
```